# Create unique Id, enumerate different row values while reading multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I will like to make an unique id for this based on game name and year. The main focus is on the col name.

I have multiple files:

```
Name   Year    Level   
Pikachu   2007    30
Pikachu   2007    20
Raichu    2007    20
Mew       2007    35
```

---

```
Name   Year    Level   
Pikachu   2008    50
Pikachu   2008    40
Raichu    2008    55
Mew       2008    55
```

---

---

```
Pokemon   Year    Level   
Squirtle  2008    50
Pidgey    2008    40
Pidgey    2008    55
Ekans     2008    55
```

---

This is the Result I want:

```
  Game     Name   Year    Level    Id 
Pokemon   Pikachu   2007    30     1
Pokemon   Pikachu   2007    20     1 
Pokemon   Raichu    2007    20     2
Pokemon    Mew      2007    35     3
Pokemon   Pikachu   2008    50     1
Pokemon   Pikachu   2008    40     1
Pokemon   Raichu    2008    55     2
Pokemon   Mewtwo    2008    55     3
Pokemon   Squirtle  2008    60     1
Pokemon    Pidgey   2008    45     2
Pokemon    Pidgey   2008    52     2
Pokemon    Ekans    2008    51     3
```

I've tried with this:

```
for file in files:
   df = pd.read_csv(file,header=0)
   df['Game'] = 'Pokemon'
   for i, p in enumerate(df['Pokemon'].unique(), 1):
       df.loc[i-1,'id'] = i
       df.loc[i-1, 'Pokemon'] = p
   df['Id'] = df['Id'].astype('int')
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the `Id` column in the requested result you posted is correct? And if so, how do you determine the `Id` for each row?

Comment: This is the id i want, because in each file, new id will be formed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) per each `DataFrame`, for final big `DataFrame` create list and last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file,header=0)
    df['Game'] = 'Pokemon'
    df['id'] = pd.factorize(df['Name'])[0] + 1
    out.append(df)

df = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
        Name  Year  Level     Game  id
0    Pikachu  2007     30  Pokemon   1
1    Pikachu  2007     20  Pokemon   1
2     Raichu  2007     20  Pokemon   2
3        Mew  2007     35  Pokemon   3
4    Pikachu  2008     50  Pokemon   1
5    Pikachu  2008     40  Pokemon   1
6     Raichu  2008     55  Pokemon   2
7        Mew  2008     55  Pokemon   3
8   Squirtle  2008     50  Pokemon   1
9     Pidgey  2008     40  Pokemon   2
10    Pidgey  2008     55  Pokemon   2
11     Ekans  2008     55  Pokemon   3
```

Comment: I might be tempted to use `df['id'] = df.groupby(['Name'], sort=False).ngroup() + 1` just in case it turns out the `id` requires more than one column to calculate id